# Iterator seems to be losing data java

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator, hashmap

I've got a method that returns a list of hashmaps (the data comes from a ResultSet).
While trying to use an iterator to loop through the data and convert it to a String array, I was finding that the code was not working - It seemed to be losing half of my array data while doing the loop.

When swapping it to use a for loop rather than an iterator, the data was not lost. I tried using both an `Iterator()` and `ListIterator()` to no avail

Here is my original code (that wasn't working):

```
public String[][] getLayoutEdges() throws SQLException {
    ArrayList<String[]> returnArray = new ArrayList<>();

    List<HashMap> layoutEdges = db.getLayoutEdgesFromDatabase();
    ListIterator<HashMap> edgesIterator = layoutEdges.listIterator();

    while(edgesIterator.hasNext()) {
        ArrayList<String> tmpList = new ArrayList<>();
        tmpList.add(edgesIterator.next().get("fromnode").toString());
        tmpList.add(edgesIterator.next().get("tonode").toString());
        tmpList.add(edgesIterator.next().get("distance").toString());

        String[] tmpStr = new String[tmpList.size()];
        returnArray.add(tmpList.toArray(tmpStr));

    } 

    String[][] rtn = new String[returnArray.size()][returnArray.size()];
    return returnArray.toArray(rtn);
}
```

Here is the code that does work:

```
public String[][] getLayoutEdges() throws SQLException {
    ArrayList<String[]> returnArray = new ArrayList<>();

    List<HashMap> layoutEdges = db.getLayoutEdgesFromDatabase();

    for(HashMap tmp : layoutEdges) {
        ArrayList<String> tmpList = new ArrayList<>();
        tmpList.add(tmp.get("fromnode").toString());
        tmpList.add(tmp.get("tonode").toString());
        tmpList.add(tmp.get("distance").toString());

        String[] tmpStr = new String[tmpList.size()];
        returnArray.add(tmpList.toArray(tmpStr));
    }

    String[][] rtn = new String[returnArray.size()][returnArray.size()];
    return returnArray.toArray(rtn);
}
```

Can anybody tell me why the iterator wasn't working? I'm okay with using a for loop, i just can't for the life of me work out why the original iterator code I wrote wasn't keeping all my data. Wondering if there's a step i'm missing or whether I was trying to use the wrong solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calling `edgesIterator.next()` three times for each iteration of the loop in your first snippet, which I'm pretty sure you don't want to do. Just don't do that:

```
while (edgesIterator.hasNext()) {
    HashMap tmp = edgesIterator.next();
    tmpList.add(tmp.get("fromnode").toString());
    tmpList.add(tmp.get("tonode").toString());
    tmpList.add(tmp.get("distance").toString());
    String[] tmpStr = new String[tmpList.size()];
    returnArray.add(tmpList.toArray(tmpStr));
}
```

As an aside, if you could avoid using raw types in your API, it would generally be cleaner - I'm talking about the use of `HashMap` here.

I would also generally favour the second version of your code anyway - unless you *need* to use the iterator explicitly for some reason, let the syntactic sugar of the enhanced for loop do it for you automatically.

Comment: Just as I suspected...a stupid oversight. That makes complete sense - thank you for the prompt reply!

Comment: Why do you suggest avoiding raw types, and can I define them in things such as `List<HashMap>` as `List<HashMap<String>>` ? (Netbeans is telling me that comes as an error)

Comment: @CynePhoba12: Raw types lose type information, meaning you have to cast or call `toString()` all over the place. (Assuming your map is really a `Map<String, String>`, you could remove all your `toString()` calls.) You'd need to specify two type arguments for `HashMap`, as it has keys and values - and I'd personally use `List<Map<String, String>>` rather than making the `HashMap` explicit. Without knowing more it's hard to give full code, but I suggest you experiment.

Answer (score 1):

Because of these lines :

```
tmpList.add(edgesIterator.next().get("fromnode").toString());
tmpList.add(edgesIterator.next().get("tonode").toString());
tmpList.add(edgesIterator.next().get("distance").toString());
```

The moment you are calling edgesIterator.next() its moving the cursor to the next element.

Comment: `layoutEdges` is a `List<HashMap>` - it doesn't have an `entrySet()`. While the OP doesn't *need* to use `listIterator()` as far as we can tell, there's nothing wrong with the way they're doing it.